# HTML Editable Table : Add new row including radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Let's say, I have an editable html table. In one of these table cells it contains radio button. What I want is to add a new row button. When I click the button the new row should contain same radio buttons with **new group**.

Let's say, when the page initially loads the table is something like:

```
<table id="exp02Table" class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bengaliText">
      <th> (P)</th>
      <th> (a cm)</th>
      <th> (b cm)</th>
      <th> (c cm)</th>
      <th> L=(a-b) cm</th>
      <th> H = (c-b) cm </th>
      <th> P = H±h</th>
      <th> PV = (H±h)*L</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="exp02TBody">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p> <label> <input value="0" checked name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপ</span> </label> </p>
        <p> <label> <input value="1" name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের বেশী</span> </label> </p>
        <p> <label> <input value="2" name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের কম</span> </label> </p>
      </td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> You can see the first column has radio buttons with **group1** group name.

What I am trying to say is that next time when I click the add new row button the new row should

- **include same radio buttons with new group name group 2, group 3 .... and the first radio option should be checked**
- and the other **td (table data) should be contenteditable with no
  values in it**:

  ```
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p> <label> <input value="0" checked name="group2" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপ</span> </label> </p>
      <p> <label> <input value="1" name="group2" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের বেশী</span> </label> </p>
      <p> <label> <input value="2" name="group2" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের কম</span> </label> </p>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable></td>
    <td contenteditable></td>
    <td contenteditable></td>
    <td contenteditable></td>
    <td contenteditable></td>
    <td contenteditable></td>
    <td contenteditable></td>
  </tr>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add a new object to your Document Object Model (DOM) after interaction with some kind of elements such as a button, some JavaScript might be required. See the following fiddle:

In plain JavaScript:

```js
let i = 1;
function AddRow() {
  i++;
  let tbody = document.getElementById("exp02TBody");
  let tr = document.createElement("tr");
  
  //The HTML for the row. Obviously not as readable in JavaScript so there might a bit cleaner solution to this but at least it's functional:
  tr.innerHTML =
    "<td><p><label><input value='0' checked name='group-" + i + "' type='radio'> বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপ</label></p><p><label><input value='1' name='group-" + i + "' type='radio'> বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের বেশী</label></p><p><label><input value='2' name='group-" + i + "' type='radio'> বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের কম</label></p></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td>";
    
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<table id="exp02Table" class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bengaliText">
      <th> (P)</th>
      <th> (a cm)</th>
      <th> (b cm)</th>
      <th> (c cm)</th>
      <th> L=(a-b) cm</th>
      <th> H = (c-b) cm </th>
      <th> P = H±h</th>
      <th> PV = (H±h)*L</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="exp02TBody">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p> <label> <input value="0" checked name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপ</span> </label> </p>
        <p> <label> <input value="1" name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের বেশী</span> </label> </p>
        <p> <label> <input value="2" name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের কম</span> </label> </p>
      </td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="AddRow()">Add row</button>
```

I added a `<button onclick="AddRow()">Add row</button>` to your DOM (in the HTML) and I added a script with the function `Addrow()` (please see the fiddle for referencce).

In jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let i = 1;
  $("#row-button").on("click", function() {
    i++;
    $("#exp02TBody").append("<tr><td><p><label><input value='0' checked name='group-" + i + "' type='radio'> বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপ</label></p><p><label><input value='1' name='group-" + i + "' type='radio'> বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের বেশী</label></p><p><label><input value='2' name='group-" + i + "' type='radio'> বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের কম</label></p></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td><td contenteditable></td></tr>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="exp02Table" class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bengaliText">
      <th> (P)</th>
      <th> (a cm)</th>
      <th> (b cm)</th>
      <th> (c cm)</th>
      <th> L=(a-b) cm</th>
      <th> H = (c-b) cm </th>
      <th> P = H±h</th>
      <th> PV = (H±h)*L</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="exp02TBody">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p> <label> <input value="0" checked name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপ</span> </label> </p>
        <p> <label> <input value="1" name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের বেশী</span> </label> </p>
        <p> <label> <input value="2" name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের কম</span> </label> </p>
      </td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
      <td contenteditable></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="row-button">Add row</button>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I've no problem if you add jQuery. That would be appreciated more :D

Comment: I added a jQuery sample @Shunjid .

Comment: Thanks a lot. Accepting your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help

HTML

```
<table id="exp02Table" class="responsive-table table table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr class="bengaliText">
    <th> (P)</th>
    <th> (a cm)</th>
    <th> (b cm)</th>
    <th> (c cm)</th>
    <th> L=(a-b) cm</th>
    <th> H = (c-b) cm </th>
    <th> P = H±h</th>
    <th> PV = (H±h)*L</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="exp02TBody">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <p> <label> <input value="0" checked name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপ</span> </label> </p>
    <p> <label> <input value="1" name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের বেশী</span> </label> </p>
    <p> <label> <input value="2" name="group1" type="radio" /> <span>বায়ু মন্ডলের চাপের কম</span> </label> </p>
  </td>
  <td contenteditable></td>
  <td contenteditable></td>
  <td contenteditable></td>
  <td contenteditable></td>
  <td contenteditable></td>
  <td contenteditable></td>
  <td contenteditable></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<button class="addN">
 Add New
</button>
```

JS

```
$(".addN").on("click", function(e){
 var lastTr = $("#exp02TBody").find("tr:last-child")
 var clone = lastTr.clone();
 var groupName  = lastTr.find("input[type='radio']").attr("name");
 var lastGroupNum = parseInt(groupName.match(/\d/g).join(""));
 var newGroup = "group"+(lastGroupNum+1);
 clone.find("input[type='radio']").attr("name", newGroup);
 $("#exp02TBody").append(clone);
})
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuaibkhan1911/3mbovsez/18/)

Comment: You are very close to it. But I asked to include same radio buttons with new group name group 2, group 3 .... and the first radio option should be checked

and the other td (table data) should be contenteditable with no values in it: